# JQuery progress bar plugin shows NaN%

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plugins

So I'm working on a project where I want to display the upload progress of a video. I'm using this plugin: [JQuery ring progress bar](http://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Animated-Circular-Progress-Indicator-Plugin-With-jQuery-Canvas.html).

When I submit the form the text in the div looks like **NaN%** and nothing more.

Please help. I'm new to ajax and jQuery.

This is my jQuery:

```
var options = {
    height: "100px",
    width: "100px",
    line_width: 2,
    color: "#3281ff",
    starting_position: 25,
    percent: 0,
    text: "percent"
};

var progress_circle = $("#progress-circle").gmpc(options);
    //console.log(progress_circle);
    //http://malsup.com/jquery/form/progress2.html
    (function() {
    $('form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function() {
            var percentVal = '0%';
            console.log('test');
            progress_circle.gmpc('percent', percentVal);
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete;

            progress_circle.gmpc('percent', percentVal);
            //progress_circle.gmpc('animate', percentVal);
        },
        success: function() {
            setTimeout(7000);
            window.location.replace("/1");
        },
    }); 
    })();
```

And this is the div that is important:

```
Upload progress:
<div id="progress-circle">

</div>
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: In your `beforeSend`, try `var percentVal = 0;`

Comment: This did it! Thanks! You got to love programming mistakes, right...